# C++ default arguments in template function

Tags: c++, templates

I struggle with templates. In my template class `test` I want to have method `Find`. This method should be able to take optional argument `max` and optional argument `filter`. Filter can represent **pointer to function, functor or lambda expression**.

Problem is when i try to compile the code. I get an error: `no matching function for call to 'test<std::basic_string<char>, int>::Find(const char [5])'` Which should not happen because I specified default parameters.

Can anybody please explain how to manage these templates correctly ? Should I use `std::function` for `filter` instead of `template <typename F>` ?

```
template <typename X>
bool cmp (const X &) { return true; }

template <typename A, typename B>
class test
{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename F>
    set<A,B> Find(A place, int max = 0, const F & filter = cmp) // problem, won't use cmp as default
    {
        // .. do something
    };
};

int main()
{
    test<string,int> lines;
    lines . Find ( "test" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cmp` is not a function - it's a function template, an infinite family of functions. You need to specify which of them you want to use as a default argument; e.g. `const F & filter = cmp<A>`

Comment: Tried `cmp<A>` and still get the same error.

Comment: Hmm. I thought `F` would be deduced from default argument, but apparently not. You can fix it with `template <typename F = decltype(cmp<A>)>...`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/HFLP80279)

Comment: Thank you it works. Can you explain why it works this way ?

Comment: The compiler needs to determine all template parameters at the point the template is used. They could be specified explicitly (as in `test<string, int>`), or deduced from arguments of a function call, or provided with defaults. If none of these succeeds, the program is ill-formed. In your example, `F` was not specified explicitly, nor is there an argument from which it could be deduced; the only remaining possibility is the default.